# Node Labels : Pygraphviz

Tags: python, pygraphviz

I am following the tutorials (or test code as shown [here](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec234) and my trees look completely different than the way they are shown in the documentation. My trees lack any kind of information such as the node labels, distance scores etc. I looked at the Phylo [wiki](http://biopython.org/wiki/Phylo_cookbook#Graphics) but it looks to be incomplete. I would really like to have the node labelled with the respective name(from the phyloxml file) and also the branch length. I am posting a link of my phyloxml file below. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

PhyloXML file : http://pastie.org/9661690

This is how my graph looks now:
[image]

Code:

```
import pylab
from Bio import Phylo

tree = Phylo.read('allseqs.dnd', 'newick')
tree.rooted=True
Phylo.draw_graphviz(tree, ,prog = 'neato', node_size =500)
pylab.show()
```